# Top and bottom of Photo captured using CameraCaptureUI is getting stretched

Tags: c#, image-processing, camera, uwp, windows

```
CameraCaptureUI captureUI = new CameraCaptureUI();
captureUI.PhotoSettings.Format = CameraCaptureUIPhotoFormat.Jpeg;
captureUI.PhotoSettings.MaxResolution = Windows.Media.Capture.CameraCaptureUIMaxPhotoResolution.HighestAvailable;
StorageFile file = await captureUI.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);
```

This shows up the camera, and I am able to preview and click to capture the image. The captured image is shown in another window over the original camera image windows. I am able to crop and click to save this captured image.

However, right after I click save, the image is getting stretched, and after it is saved, it remains stretched as well. In essence, the image I capture and save is being stretched,

I tried removing the crop and it works fine, but I need the crop feature as well.

What am I doing wrong? Should I be using any other values for these settings?

This was working fine till December if I remember correctly.

Any help here is appreciated. Screenshots added below

[image], [image], [image]

Comment: Have you checked if this also happens with [MediaCapture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/basic-photo-video-and-audio-capture-with-mediacapture) scenario? (you can check [the sample app from GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraAdvancedCapture))

Comment: Also - can you share a repro sample?

Comment: I tried this sample but it is also giving the same issue. Seems like a issue with Microsoft SDK update. You can try this sample to check. As I said if the cropping is set to false no issues. https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CameraCaptureUI-Sample-845a53ac

Comment: I will check this one after I return from work, will give you a sign how it looks on my side.

Comment: @Romasz were you able to check this issue?

Comment: Thanks for pinging with this and sorry, I totally forgot. I've just put this into my phone's calendar, so will check the issue this evening.

Comment: The sample you have linked seems to be for W8.1 and seems that you are asking about UWP - do you have a repro for that?

Comment: Actually I am using the same code in my UWP app. Unfortunately I cant give the code I work on ill try to create a small snippet.

Comment: This isn't 'stretched' though; it's repeating a single line of pixels. Not sure about uwp, but overall, this should be fixable in a post-processing step by comparing image lines until you find two that are no longer the same.